# CSS Spacing Cross-Compatibility Issues

Tags: css, cross-browser, spacing

I'm coding my first site, and didn't realize how frustrating cross-browser compatibility would be. Here's my site: http://www.tommaxwell.me. It looks the way I want it to in Safari and Chrome (maybe because they're Webkit?), but in Opera and Firefox, the spacing between the first header and the tagline is way too much. I can't figure out how to fix this. I read something about CSS Reset's, but I'm not sure how to use it or exactly what it is.

CSS:

```
body {
background-image:url(209241_2453996366505_1946848896_o.gif);
background-position:center center;
background-attachment:fixed;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
background-size: 100% 100%, auto;

padding:0;
margin:0;



}

@font-face {
font-family: 'klavika_rgregular';
src: url('klavika-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('klavika-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('klavika-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('klavika-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('klavika-regular-webfont.svg#klavika_rgregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}



@font-face {
font-family: 'klavika_mediummedium';
src: url('klavikamedium-osf-webfont.eot');
src: url('klavikamedium-osf-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('klavikamedium-osf-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('klavikamedium-osf-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('klavikamedium-osf-webfont.svg#klavika_mediummedium') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}


h1 {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10%;
font-family: klavika_mediummedium;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size: 6.250em;
font-weight: 400;
}


p {
position: relative;
top:-8%;
text-align: center;
font-family: klavika_rgregular;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size: 1.875em;
font-weight: 400;
}




ul {
position: relative;
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: 37%;
font-family: klavika_mediummedium;
}


ul li {
font-size: 2.500em;
font-weight: 400;
float: left;
padding-right: 3%;
```

}

Comment: you should write your HTML markup in a proper way below many of people answered you about how to write proper HTML markup and CSS. So read the articles that will help you.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose [**HTML5 Boilerplate**](http://html5boilerplate.com/) as your default template, it comes with [**Normalize CSS**](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) which resets the default settings of all browsers.

HTML5 Boilerplate has comments on almost each line of CSS and HTML, these comments makes it more easy to use.

Your solution is in setting `line-height: 30px;` to `h1` element because `h1` has too large font-size so you have to adjust line-height

Comment: Your solution worked, and I'll check out HTML5 Boilerplate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use doctype(first line in html file).
For better CSS and cross-browser compatibility use reset:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

Just replace my `p tag` class into your css :-

**CSS**

```
p {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: klavika_rgregular;
    font-size: 1.875em;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```